# Badge for having a certain amount of accepted answers

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

I would like to see a badge for having a certain amount of accepted answers.

-- for example I have `50` answers which are accepted so maybe a badge for this to reward good answerers,

but one that doesn't require any number of votes, just the specific number of accepted answers.

and then `150` and so on.

- this to encourage people to answer good answers and answer much  just to be accepted and to win this badge

Comment: Compared to the accept-rate this is actually not a bad idea. I'd be worried that it encourages people to accept answers just to get the badge though. Maybe accepted 70% of answers and asked 10 or more questions or something like that?

Comment: I think he means the badge for the answerer, not the acceptor.

Comment: no , if people accept answers its not them who get the badge , but the one who asked as it helpful answer

Comment: yes lance i mean like what u said